# Hierarchy of infinites, doesn't apply here, even though it should be very easy?

Tags: calculus

> **Exercise 4.5**: $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{3\ln n + n^2}{2e^{-n}+n^3}$$
>    a) converges to $0$
>
> b) converges to $S > 0$
>
> c) diverges to $+\infty$
>
> d) none of the others

I tried to solve this by excluding the logarithm and leaving just n to the power of 3 in the denominator, but still the exercise tells me its C the right answer, how is that possible?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't forget the numerator has an $n^2$ besides the logarithm in the numerator.

Answer (score 2):

You've thrown away too much.

When you "throw away silly terms," you are *not* left with just $1\over n^3$; instead, you're left with $n^2\over n^3$, or $1\over n$.

That is, you throw away $3\ln n$ since it's "dominated by" $n^2$, and throw away $2e^{-n}$ since it's "dominated by" $n^3$; but this still leaves $n^2$ on the top as well as $n^3$ on the bottom.

Now, what do you know about the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n}$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  As you stated, the terms $2 \log(n)$ in the numerator and $2e^{-n}$ are both irrelevant.

If you remove those terms, you are left with:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n^3} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}.$$

Hope that helps.

PS: Most mathematicians would frown upon a student dropping terms that appear to be irrelevant without justification. They would prefer to show that 
$$
 \frac{2 \log(n) + n^2}{2e^{-n} + n^3} > \frac{1}{2 n}
$$
for all $n> 1000$.  If you establish such an inequality, then the fact that $\sum_n \frac1{2n}$ diverges would prove that the original sum diverges.